# Java swing: format content inside dialog

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog

I am having some issues trying to format JComponent locations inside of a dialog. I feel like this is a question that has an answer already but I had some issues finding information.

I've tried using setLocation on the elements, using a custom JOptionPane/JDialog (not sure if I did those correctly though) but they always ignore the formatting of the positions. and all the elements come out in a horizontal line

[image]

Ideally I would like the class names at the top, the 3 member lists in the middle and the button on the bottom.
I am creating the dialog like so:

```
JPanel createClass = new NewClass();
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(GUI.this, 
        createClass, "Create a class",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

and NewClass()(extends JPanel) looks like this:

```
//initializes the values
className = new JTextField(10);
superName = new JTextField(10);
publicMem = new DefaultListModel<String>();
protectedMem = new DefaultListModel<String>();
privateMem = new DefaultListModel<String>();
publicMem.addElement("Test");
publicMem.addElement("Test");
pubMemList = new JList(publicMem);
protMemList = new JList(protectedMem);
privMemList = new JList(privateMem);
pubMemList.setLocation(0,0);
newMember = new ButtonController(memberCommand);

//add Components to the JPanel
add(new JLabel("Class Name:"));
add(className);
add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
add(new JLabel("Super Class Name:"));
add(superName);
add(new JLabel("\n"));
add(new JLabel("Public Members :"));
add(pubMemList);
add(new JLabel("Protected Members :"));
add(protMemList);
add(new JLabel("Private Members :"));
add(privMemList);
add(newMember);
```

So if anyone could point me in the right direction or to another similar post that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a layout manager, same as you would with `JFrame` or `JPanel`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson the simplicity of your answer shows how much Java GUI I know. I searched java layout manager and it looks like it is exactly what I needed, thanks for the tip. I dont see where to mark your answer as the best one though.

Comment: please post complete code that replicate your issue.

Comment: An approach is to get the idea of the GUI you want to develop as a sketch, first, and then build it to as a GUI using Swing. Here is the Oracle's Java tutorials on: [Creating GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). See the topics Using Components and Laying Out Components Within a Container.

Comment: `I dont see where to mark your answer as the best one though.` - you can only "accept" an answer as the best one. This is just a comment so you can't accept it.  `and all the elements come out in a horizontal line ` - the default layout manager for a panel is the FlowLayout so they appear on a line.  You can check out the Swing Tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. Also, note you can nest panels which can use different layout managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Ideally I would like the class names at the top, the 3 member lists in the middle and the button on the bottom"**
You could use a `BorderLayout` to achieve it. The following snippet may help you to get started:

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //now add 3 panel as containers for top, center and bottom content
    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //manage layout and add content to top container
    top.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//actually it the default
    top.add(new JLabel("Class Name:"));
    JTextField className = new JTextField(10);
    top.add(className);
    top.add(new JLabel("Super Class Name:"));
    JTextField superName = new JTextField(10);
    top.add(superName);

    //todo manage layout and add content to center container
    //todo manage layout and add content to bottom container
```